# If I use a static method inside a class, why can't I use any of the class's constructors?

Tags: javascript

I want to organize my code a bit, so I've been using classes to distribute the methods associated with a certain action. Like a UI class to handle the UI, a Storage class to handle the storage, and a Weather class to handle my weather API calls. I initialized these classes in the main `script.js` file, but I've realized a lot of these methods have to be called outside the `script.js` file — like a UI method in the Storage class etc. So, after some googling, I've learned there's a thing called static methods, which allow you to call the method outside its particular class. These worked well until:

I have an API key which I keep as a constructor of the GetWeather class and I can't call it in a static method, despite it being in the same class. What's going on, and what can I do to fix it?

```
class GetWeather {
  constructor() {
    this.key = "24c69c3dd3a07fdbXXXXXXXX";
  }

  async generateWeatherByPlace(place, measurement) {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${place}&${
        measurement ? "units=metric" : "units=imperial"
      }&appid=${this.key}`
    );

    const responseData = await response.json();

    return responseData;
  }

  static async generateWeatherByID(weatherID) {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${weatherID}&appid=${this.key}`
    );

    const responseData = await response.json();

    return responseData;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because static methods are *by design* not part of any instance. The constructor is completely irrelevant when it comes to static methods. If you need instance data, then you need instance methods. If you need non-instance related operations, then you can use static methods.

Comment: "*a thing called static methods, which allow you to call the method outside its particular class*" no, that's not really how it works. It allows you to call methods outside a *constructed instance* - without calling `myInstance = new MyClass` first, for example. You still call it within the context of *the class itself* - e.g., `MyClass.myStaticMethod()` as opposed to `myInstance.myMethod()`

Comment: @vlaz, thanks for the quick answer. How would you go about referencing that key inside the static method?

Comment: I wouldn't. I'd probably make a singleton instance that gets imported everywhere. Makes a lot more sense here. If you need a class with all static methods, then that's a sign of weak OOP. You may as well just export functions.

Comment: I don't see any reason for this to be a class - it keeps no state and seems to serve as just a container of functions and static data. That's why you're having troubles using it like a class properly. If it were me, I'd just move the key outside of the class definition and make it a constant, since that's what it is.

Comment: "*I want to organize my code a bit, so I've been using classes*" - don't. First, use objects to organise the code. Plain, simple objects with methods that you can call. Make them global. Call them "modules" if you want - an UI module, a storage module, etc. When you find that you need a kind of object multiple times, *that's* the point where you should learn about classes.